# Is it a bad practice to use "translate" functionality to get a variable in JS script

Tags: magento2

I am looking for a way of getting a store view specific variable in my JS mixin.
I have had no success getting it from my admin config, which would be ideal.

So now  I have the idea of using `$.mage.__("storeview specific variable")` in my JS, and in my `.csv` file I would "translate" it to the variable I need.

Is there any reason I should not do this?

Comment: Nope. That's exactly why they provide that functionality in JS.

Comment: @AndréFerraz Can you put it into an answer? If anyone wonders the same thing, it will be helpful:)